# Как отредактировать реализацию метода в сборке?

Tags: c#, .net, codedom

Пишу программу, которая принимает на входе .NET-сборку А, модифицирует её и возвращает уже сборку В. Например, нужно изменить часть кода определённого метода. Сначала решила использовать `Mono.Cecil` для этих целей. Застряла, дойдя до списка объектов класса Instruction нужного мне метода. Значения свойств этих объектов интуитивно непонятны мне и для их определения, я так поняла, мне нужно изучить IL. Решила попробовать `System.CodeDom`. Изучив документацию, не могу найти функционал для загрузки сборки, которую планирую обрабатывать. Возможно ли используя `System.CodeDom` загрузить сборку и модифицировать её?

Comment: CodeDom∈Obsolete; DLL⊃IL; DOM=decompile(IL); ILSpy∈Decompile; edit∈Hardcore∩Pain.

Comment: @Kyubey, шифруешься? :-) а если словами, что твой комментарий значит? :)

Comment: [#](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols)

Comment: @Kyubey мы программисты, а не математики(

Comment: "мы программисты, а не математики(" - жаль, операции над множествами не только математикам нужны, впрочем ладно. По сути, вам нужно не просто загрузить сборку, а декомпилировать ее - для этого надо знать IL. В крайнем случае можно подменить байт-код, но для этого надо еще лучше знать IL, а также внутренние структуры сборки и манифеста, чтобы не получить "тыкву" на выходе. Кроме того, сборка может иметь подпись. После такого изменения подпись, разумеется, станет невалидной. Если очень интересно - можно посмотреть исходники ILSpy, они в свободном доступе, но проблему с подписью это не решит.